# Defining Maven properties used in dependency specification outside the pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I should preface my question by saying I have only cursory familiarity with Maven.

I am working on a (forked) project which requires a private third party dependency that must be provided by anyone wishing to perform a build. Upstream accomplishes this by defining a hardcoded path in `<properties>`, but this requires editing the POM if that path does not match on a given system. I am attempting to adjust the POM such that this property is defined in an external file (that can be excluded from source control, etc.)

I tried to use [`properties-maven-plugin`](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/), but I could not get it to work. As far as I understand, this plugin injects properties *after* dependencies have been parsed; and so the build fails trying to resolve a path with a literal (unexpanded) `${dep.path}` in it.

The only working solution I have found so far is to define the property on the command line with `-Ddep.path=/the/path/...`, but this is *quite* cumbersome. I tried leveraging `.mvn/maven.config` to store this argument, but the path to the dependency will include spaces on all platforms and so it is parsed incorrectly (as two separate arguments.)

To put it in code, my issue is:

```xml
<properties>
  <!-- I would like to define this property in an external file -->
  <dep.path>C:\hardcoded\win32\path</dep.path>
</properties>

<!-- while still able to use that property like so -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
    <systemPath>${dep.path}/a.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Best is to define the needed deps as a usual dependeny. The required dependency should be installed into local repo via `mvn install:install-file` or while using a repository manager deployed to that repo manager...